# Array sort and push the value into same key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one array like below structure

```
$usersAttemptsInfo = [
    "200" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "300" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 4],// less than 5
    "400" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "500" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 3],// less than 5 & less than 4
    "600" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "700" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 2],// less than 5 & & less than 4 & less than 3
    "800" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "900" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 4],// less than 5
    "1001" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 3],// less than 5 & & less than 4
    "1002" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "1003" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 2],// less than 5 & & less than 4 & & less than 3
];
```

when we are looping first time `totalCorrectQuestion` is 5, so we have take count of less than 5.
according to my array total 6 is there for <5. so i have to do the calculation **6/12 * 100**.  `12` is total count of `$usersAttemptsInfo`. array 6/12*100 = 50

`$usersAttemptsInfo` wherever `totalCorrectQuestion = 5` we have to update `percentile` key and value is `50`. `percentile` value is there in `$usersAttemptsInfo` then loop should not run.

next loop will run `totalCorrectQuestion` is 4, so we have take count of less than 4. according to my array total 5 is there for <4. so i have to do the calculation 5/12*100 = 41.6.  `$usersAttemptsInfo` wherever `totalCorrectQuestion = 4` we have to update `percentile` key and value is `41`

next loop will run `totalCorrectQuestion` is 3, so we have take count of less than 3. according to my array total 2 is there for <3. so i have to do the calculation 2/12*100 = 17.6.

`$usersAttemptsInfo` wherever `totalCorrectQuestion = 4` we have to update `percentile` key and value is `41`. next loop will run `totalCorrectQuestion` is 2, so we have take count of less than 2. according to my array total 0 is there for <2 so i have to do the calculation **0/12 * 100**.

my code

```
$finalResult = [];
if (!empty($usersAttemptsInfo)) {
    $keys = array_keys($usersAttemptsInfo);
    array_multisort(array_column($usersAttemptsInfo, 'totalCorrectQuestion'), SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $usersAttemptsInfo, $keys);
    $usersAttemptsInfo = array_combine($keys, $usersAttemptsInfo);
    $totalStudentAttemptedWorksheet = count($usersAttemptsInfo);
    foreach ($usersAttemptsInfo as $key => $userAttemptData) {
        $indexpossition = array_search($key, array_keys($usersAttemptsInfo));
        $percentile = $indexpossition / $totalStudentAttemptedWorksheet * 100;
        $finalResult[$key] = $userAttemptData;
        $finalResult[$key]["percentile"] = $percentile;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalResult);
```

Expected output

```
$expected = [
    "200" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5, "precentile" => 50],
    "300" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 4, "percentile" => 41],
    "400" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5, "precentile" => 50],
    "500" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 3, "percentile" => 17],
    "600" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5, "precentile" => 50],
    "700" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 2, "percentile" => 0],
    "800" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5, "precentile" => 50],
    "900" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 4, "percentile" => 41],
    "1001" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 3, "percentile" => 17],
    "1002" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5, "precentile" => 50],
    "1003" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 2, "percentile" => 0],
];
```

I am not getting which logic I have to use. I couldn't get my expected answer.

Comment: "1000" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 6, "percentile" => bla]   , is this right in answer

Comment: percentile has to be calculated for all (same logic for first time loop run), for example i had given bla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$usersAttemptsInfo = [
    "200" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "300" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 4],
    "400" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "500" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 3],
    "600" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "700" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 2],
    "800" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "900" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 4],
    "1000" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 6],
    "1001" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 3],
    "1002" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 5],
    "1003" => ["totalQuesAttempted" => 10, "totalCorrectQuestion" => 2]
];




$totalUsersAttemptsInfo = count($usersAttemptsInfo);

function percentile($totalCorrectQuestion){
    global $totalUsersAttemptsInfo;
    return round($totalCorrectQuestion / $totalUsersAttemptsInfo * 100);

}

$finalResult = [];
if (!empty($usersAttemptsInfo)) {
    foreach ($usersAttemptsInfo as $key => $userAttemptData) {
        $finalResult[$key] = $userAttemptData;
        $total = 0;
        foreach($usersAttemptsInfo as $userAttemptData1){
            if($userAttemptData1['totalCorrectQuestion'] < $userAttemptData['totalCorrectQuestion']){
                $total++;
            }
        }
        $finalResult[$key]["percentile"] = percentile($total);
    }
}
ksort($finalResult); // to sort by key
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalResult);


<pre>Array
(
    [200] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 5
            [percentile] => 50
        )

    [300] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 4
            [percentile] => 33
        )

    [400] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 5
            [percentile] => 50
        )

    [500] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 3
            [percentile] => 17
        )

    [600] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 5
            [percentile] => 50
        )

    [700] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 2
            [percentile] => 0
        )

    [800] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 5
            [percentile] => 50
        )

    [900] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 4
            [percentile] => 33
        )

    [1000] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 6
            [percentile] => 92
        )

    [1001] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 3
            [percentile] => 17
        )

    [1002] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 5
            [percentile] => 50
        )

    [1003] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 2
            [percentile] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: I want to do calculation for entire loop not only mentioned values(5 & 4)

Comment: totalCorrectQuestion is 3, so we have take count of less than 3, according to my array total 2 is there for <3. so i have to do the calculation 2/12 * 100.

Comment: 2/12*100 = 17.6

Comment: But your output showing `totalCorrectQuestion = 3`  means percentile is showing 33, this is wrong, but first two percentile is looks good

Comment: Please put a valid expected ouput

Comment: Why 5 is 50, it should be 41

Comment: Output of 6  . ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218704/discussion-between-rahul-juneja-devops-and-nallammal-t).

Comment: 5 is 50 only, how come 41 ?

Comment: 5/12*100 = 41.666

Comment: when we are looping first time totalCorrectQuestion is 5, so we have take count of less than 5. according to my array total 6 is there for <5. so i have to do the calculation 6/12 * 100.

Comment: sorted , check now

Comment: Thank you so much,If possible can you explain the code(step by step)

Comment: First loop is to get each row, and second loop to calculate total totalCorrectQuestions that are less from current row's totalCorrectQuestions to calculate percentile

Comment: `totalCorrectQuestion` 5 count is 6,so loop will run for 6 time?

Comment: loop will run 12 times and count how many times a values is less than current totalCorrectQuestion, So ran 12 times but found only 6 values

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want to get the percentiles across the board, right? Not just for your specific example?

First, calculate how many people got each score

```php
$counts = [];

// Count how many people have each score
foreach ($usersAttemptsInfo as $userAttemptData) {
    $r = $userAttemptData['totalCorrectQuestion'];

    // Initialize the key if it doesn't exist
    if (!array_key_exists($r, $counts)) {
        $counts[$r] = 0;
    }

    // Increment our key to flag that it is found
    $counts[$r]++;
}
```

Then, calculate their percentiles:

```php
// Our total count
$count = count($usersAttemptsInfo);

// Set percentiles
foreach ($usersAttemptsInfo as &$userAttemptData) {
    // Get our key again (we could also store this in the first loop if we really wanted)
    $r = $userAttemptData['totalCorrectQuestion'];
    
    // Count how many are less than this current correct score
    $countLessThan = array_reduce(

        // Workaround to use array_reduce but keep keys,
        // see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php#118254
        array_keys($counts),
        
        static function ($carry, $key) use ($r, $counts) {
            return $carry + ($r > $key ? $counts[$key] : 0);
        },
        0
    );

    // Turn into an integer percentage
    $userAttemptData['percentile'] = round($countLessThan / $count * 100);
}
```

This produces:

```php
[
    '200'  => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 5, 'percentile' => 50],
    '300'  => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 4, 'percentile' => 33],
    '400'  => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 5, 'percentile' => 50],
    '500'  => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 3, 'percentile' => 17],
    '600'  => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 5, 'percentile' => 50],
    '700'  => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 2, 'percentile' => 0],
    '800'  => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 5, 'percentile' => 50],
    '900'  => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 4, 'percentile' => 33],
    '1000' => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 6, 'percentile' => 92],
    '1001' => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 3, 'percentile' => 17],
    '1002' => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 5, 'percentile' => 50],
    '1003' => ['totalQuesAttempted' => 10, 'totalCorrectQuestion' => 2, 'percentile' => 0],
]
```

Comment: totalCorrectQuestion is 5 means `we have take count of less than 5.
according to my array total 6 is there for <5. so i have to do the calculation **6/12 * 100**.`

Comment: `6/12*100 = 50`

Comment: but your case totalCorrectQuestion is 5 means showing `41.6`

Comment: Please update your sample results in your question with every single value that you expect, and remove all of the `bla` because we are having a very hard time understanding what you are looking for.

Comment: @NallammalT, thank you for providing the remaining samples, that really helps. I have updated the code above and my output now matches. For completeness, I've left item `1000` in there with a count of `6`

Comment: Can you explain what "not working" means. Are you getting an exception? Is one of the results incorrect? When I run it through a REPL it appears to be correct: https://repl.it/repls/AttentiveSnoopySearchservice#main.php